# Good alternative to crontab for java batch programs?

Tags: java, osgi, quartz-scheduler, cron, scheduler

I've been looking for replacements for my companies current batch processing system(**java SE + crontab**), since there is a lot of java code/shell script duplication, most jobs are ETL and do very similar steps and also i want to provide platform independence instead of relying on crontab, to be more specific with our job role, the current job creation steps are this:

1. Develop a java program that meets a business requirement.
2. Test it in a production like enviroment until it meets the business requirement needs.
3. Pass it to a production server with a shell script that provides file maintenance, java prgram execution and error handling routines(avoid 2 processes of the same name running, mail log to support and developers in case of program error, check output file existence after java program ends if it's relevant for the interface), and specify recurrence data(how often will this program run).

Much of the same logic is being designed and developed into a system that contains generic   routines that these programs or "interfaces"(thats how they call it there) do independently(using copy-pasted code usually since most routines are similar), but i am still missing a very important part which i need help with, this concerns the scheduler implementation that i use, and **i need it to meet one of these two needs**:

-I want to guarantee that whenever i stop the scheduling server for a system update(due to new jobs being added, etc) or whatever other reason, those jobs that could not run due to the system being down(example is 3 jobs that could not run at 3:00 P.M. because the system was down), get to run when the server gets back up, even though their respective scheduling time is gone.

OR in case that the first thing is not possible then:

-I need a way to update the scheduler with new jobs and also update the jars that provide these jobs without restarting the scheduler(sort of like OSGi).

Either of these conditions would satisfy my requirements, and would end my search for the replacement, i've looked into Quartz, Oddjob(theres a scheduler in production with this scheduler, but it needs restarting each time you add new jobs/libraries, does not satisfy my needs) and OSGi using an application server, but i am looking for better suggestions, in case you also know better options, they are also much appreciated.

Comment: Quartz is the best of the bunch, and by a long margin. If that's not good enough, you need to write your own.

Comment: @skaffman, can you suggest configuration/features he needs?  For instance, I'd guess that he wants a JDBC-JobStore and two servers - a scheduling server, which is high-availability, and an execution server which may get bounced quite a bit.  But I don't know Quartz!

Comment: @Ed Staud, that is what i am trying to figure out, if there is a feature in Quartz(or any scheduler) that runs jobs which avoided their run time due to any downtime reason.

Comment: @skaffman Let's hope not. Since i really do not want to implement custom code for schedulers.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at http://jcrontab.sourceforge.net/

*Jcrontab is a scheduler written in Java. The project objective is to provide a fully functional schedules for Java projects.*

Comment: I will check on that and get back @ you in a few days :). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, found just what i wanted, Quartz does the trick, but i have to develop my own UI Management, FORTUNATELY, there's this project http://code.google.com/p/myschedule/ which contains all that i need(add, remove, resuming jobs), and it is cheap to run the webapp, since you can use tomcat. Now i can focus on designing reusable jobs :), thank god for Quartz!